# How to search for requested text backwards?

Tags: c#, winforms

Go to Notepad. Type in "This is a test this is a test this is a test". Put the caret to the very end of the text. Go to Edit -> Find -> Type "is" -> Set the direction to 'Up'.

Each type clicking 'Find Next', the 'is' prior to the caret is selected. Then, upon then next time typing "Find Is", the prior "is" is selected.

How can I do this in code in a similar way, using WinForm's textbox? I'm not really understanding how to search backwards for certain strings. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[String.LastIndexOf(string value, int startIndex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bc3z4t9d(v=vs.80).aspx)** method.

This method begins searching at the `startIndex` character position of the string and proceeds backwards towards the beginning until either `value` is found or the first character position has been examined.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're apparently implementing an actual search box, this code might help you. It is meant to completely emulate the Notepad search options, including the current cursor position, case (in)sensitivity, and forward/backward search. It will do automatic wraparound to the beginning of the file, and then search the text before the cursor (and the opposite for backwards search).

```
    protected Int32 DoSearch(ref String sourceText, String findText, Int32 searchStartPos, StringComparison sc, Boolean forward)
    {
        Int32 resultPos = -1;
        if (forward)
        {
            // Makes sure that if the cursor is currently ON a result, then the next result is found.
            // Not needed for backwards search, since you search before the current position in that case.
            if (sourceText.Length - findText.Length >= searchStartPos && findText.Equals(sourceText.Substring(searchStartPos, findText.Length), sc))
                searchStartPos++;

            resultPos = sourceText.IndexOf(findText, searchStartPos, sc);
            if (resultPos == -1)
                resultPos = sourceText.IndexOf(findText, 0, searchStartPos, sc);
        }
        else
        {
            resultPos = sourceText.LastIndexOf(findText, searchStartPos, sc);
            if (resultPos == -1)
            {
                Int32 start = sourceText.Length;
                Int32 length = start - searchStartPos;
                resultPos = sourceText.LastIndexOf(findText, start, length, sc);
            }
        }
        return resultPos;
    }
```

Note that the `sourceText` is handled by-reference purely because a normal string variable would be copied on function call, which is a total waste of time here; the text may be rather large, and this function never modifies the string, so just passing a pointer seems more efficient to me.

(In my full code this was further optimized in the rest of my search box code, with a TextChanged event evaluating whether the text had to be re-fetched from the text box)

This search is then typically followed by code selecting the relevant piece, using the returned `resultPos` as selection start, and `findText.Length` as selection length.